# Why isn't there a live server button in vs Code?

Tags: ide

I'm trying to make vs Code show live results on the web browser. But there isn't a button for it, they're suppose to be one.

Debugging cannot be specified because this isn't a programming issue but a text editor one

Comment: you are just rampantly misspelling variable names... learn to read the console errors and use them to find your mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two typos in your code, first one:

Lines: 44, 47, 50, 53 - you have pervious instead previous

Line: 57 - you have computition instead computation